# why is geohash different from postgis?

Tags: postgresql, flutter, postgis, geohashing

I'm a bit confused with Geohash Geoflutterfire vs Geohash postgis, and I would like to have some explanations, please.

I have a Flutter Dart application that relies on Firebase. I am using the GeoFlutterFire plugin that Geohashes the addresses for me.

So the coordinates `(47.3055771,3.4905722)` have Geohash `u06mp7tyb` after they have been processed by geoflutterfire.

I have to mass process files that I have geocoded to assign a geohash to each address line. To make my life easier, I have decided to use postgresql/postgis. And so, for the address `(47.3055771,3.4905722)` indicated, I do :

```
SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(47.3055771,3.4905722),4326),9);
```

This gives me `t09eu7qy5`, i.e. a result that is totally unusable in view of the data already entered in firebase.

Where does this discrepancy between the `u06mp7tyb` geohash and the `t09eu7qy5` geohash come from? And how to solve it

Comment: Because you confused your axes.  If you swap the args, you get the same answer

Comment: Yes… I realized my mistake just after I posted :’(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For postgis, you have to swap latitude and longitude like this :

```
SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),4326),9);
```

I've been stuck on this for two days.... ‍

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).